# Ubuntu Server 22.04 automatically installs open-vm-tools

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

When I `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade` the process installs `open-vm-tools` package.

Why is `open-vm-tools` being installed on a bare-metal server?
Could it be a dependency that I am not aware of?
Is this package assumed by developers to be useful in most cases?

Here is the output from `apt update`:

```sh
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:3 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                      
Ign:4 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease           
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Hit:6 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [833 kB]
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12.2 kB]
Get:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [789 kB]
```

And here is the output from `apt dist-upgrade`:

```sh
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapache2-mod-php8.1 open-vm-tools openssh-client openssh-server
  openssh-sftp-server php8.1 php8.1-bcmath php8.1-bz2 php8.1-cgi php8.1-cli
  php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-gd php8.1-gmp php8.1-intl php8.1-mbstring
  php8.1-mysql php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline php8.1-xml php8.1-zip
  python-apt-common python3-apt python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools
  python3-software-properties software-properties-common webmin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stop for questions like this should be to query apt.

Let's do that:

```
$ apt rdepends open-vm-tools
open-vm-tools
Reverse Depends:
  ...
  Recommends: ubuntu-server
  ...
```

Aha. There it is: `Recommends: ubuntu-server`. That's the metapackage pulling it in.

Now let's look at the Ubuntu server metapackage:

```
$ apt depends ubuntu-server
ubuntu-server
  ...
  Recommends: open-vm-tools
  ...
```

There it is, pulling in `open-vm-tools`.

- Note that it's a "recommends", not a "depends", not a "suggests". Ubuntu's default setting is to pull in "depends" and "recommends" packages, and to exclude "suggests" packages. You can change that by consulting `man apt` and `man apt-get`